# For a set like this, must there exist a function for which it is a level set?

Tags: real-analysis, graphing-functions

Our metric space is $X = [0,1]^n$. Consider a set of points $S \subset X$ such that for any $x,  x' \in S, x'_i > x_i \implies x'_j \leq x_j$ for some $j \leq n$. $S$ can be uncountable. My question is, for any such $S$, does there exist a function $\phi: [0,1]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $\phi$ is increasing (weakly) in each of its components, such that $S \subseteq L$ for some level set of $\phi$?

My question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1321907/is-there-some-set-of-2-d-points-so-that-there-does-not-exist-a-function-that-con) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136532/for-which-points-is-there-an-analytic-function-through-them?rq=1) question. Though since in my case $S$ can be uncountable, one of them comes very close to answering it but doesn't.

Edit: A previous version of this question said "analytic function". I don't need the function to be analytic. It was a mistake. I misunderstood analytic functions. My apologies.

Comment: just to be clear, by analytic function you do mean a function that can be written as a power series?

Comment: I think that the answer is negative. You could take $S$ to be a set with some sharp edges, while analytic functions do not allow them.

Comment: I don't need the function to be analytic. It was a mistake. I misunderstood analytic functions. My apologies. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: As currently phrased, constant functions work. Also what purpose does $x_i' > x_i \implies$ serve?—the condition seems the same without it.